# Published .net Core Azure app service (Linux) doesn't have permission

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-web-app-service, .net-5, puppeteer-sharp

I have a problem with downloading or executing ['puppeteer-sharp'](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp) related files in my Linux web app service. It works on local machine, which means it downloads the last version of Chrome and runs it successfully.

My app is a .net core 5 web app which named 'Web'.
Main dll (Web.dll) runs under root user with **-rw-r--r--**
permission automatically after git push and I can't change the permission with ssh:

> chmod: changing permissions of 'Web.dll': Read-only system

Exception message in software is exactly error message in **SSH** after **chmod** command:

```
System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system   
at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)   
at PuppeteerSharp.BrowserFetcher.DownloadAsync(String revision)
```

It has been published with azure CI/CI and disk layout is normal, I mean app service storage.

Run command from Azure app service log stream:

```
docker run -d -p 5420:8080 --name projectname 
-e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=projectname -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False 
-e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=projectname.azurewebsites.net 
-e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=xxxx -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 
appsvc/dotnetcore:5.0_20210607.3 dotnet Web.dll
```

SSh:

[image: SSH]

Comment: Could you share more details? How exactly are you running this? What's the disk layout? Where is `Web.dll` stored? What type of file system is that?

Comment: @omajid I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after 1 day search.

Remove the **WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE** from Azure app service **"Application settings"**